# How to make specific details of user's profile private

Tags: android

In my app, a user has a profile page which displays her/his details.I want to be able to make some of these details visible to only the `owner` and private when other users of the app view the owner's profile.How do i do this is Android?

Comment: Put a Flag in your DB, based on the flag value display which fields should be available to public. You can do this in Java code too, but the flag needs to exist.

Comment: Is this possible with Google App Engine?

Comment: have you use sqlitedatabase to display data of profile?right?

Comment: No,am using Google App Engine.I'll have to find out if it's possible to use Flags in GAE.